# Add Missing Values To Pandas Groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Quarter": [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4], 
                   "Type": ["a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d"], 
                   "Value": [4,1,3,4,7,2,9,4,1]})

   Quarter Type  Value
0        1    a      4
1        2    a      1
2        3    a      3
3        4    a      4
4        1    b      7
5        2    b      2
6        3    c      9
7        4    c      4
8        4    d      1
```

For each `Type`, there needs to be a total of 4 rows that represent one of four quarters as indicated by the `Quarter` column. So, it would look like:

```
    Quarter Type  Value
0         1    a      4
1         2    a      1
2         3    a      3
3         4    a      4
4         1    b      7
5         2    b      2
6         3    b    NaN
7         4    b    NaN
8         1    c    NaN
9         2    c    NaN
10        3    c      9
11        4    c      4
12        1    d    NaN
13        2    d    NaN
14        3    d    NaN
15        4    d      1
```

Then, where there are missing values in the `Value` column, fill the missing values using the next closest available value with the same `Type` (if it's the last quarter that is missing then fill with the third quarter):

```
    Quarter Type  Value
0         1    a      4
1         2    a      1
2         3    a      3
3         4    a      4
4         1    b      7
5         2    b      2
6         3    b      2
7         4    b      2
8         1    c      9
9         2    c      9
10        3    c      9
11        4    c      4
12        1    d      1
13        2    d      1
14        3    d      1
15        4    d      1
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are there multiple years or does each type only have four quarters?

Comment: You can assume only four quarters exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reindex`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    df['Type'].unique(),
    range(1,5)
], names=['Type', 'Quarter'])

df.set_index(['Type', 'Quarter']).reindex(idx) \
    .groupby('Type') \
    .transform(lambda v: v.ffill().bfill()) \
    .reset_index()
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a `.reset_index()` after the final `transform` and I can accept this wonderful answer!

Comment: Done. Sorry for missing it

Answer (score 4):

you can use `set_index` and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to create the missing rows you want (assuming each quarter is available in at least one type), then `ffill` and `bfill` over the columns and finally [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) and `reset_index` to go back to the original shape

```
df = df.set_index(['Type', 'Quarter']).unstack()\
       .ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)\
       .stack().reset_index()

print (df)
   Type  Quarter  Value
0     a        1    4.0
1     a        2    1.0
2     a        3    3.0
3     a        4    4.0
4     b        1    7.0
5     b        2    2.0
6     b        3    2.0
7     b        4    2.0
8     c        1    9.0
9     c        2    9.0
10    c        3    9.0
11    c        4    4.0
12    d        1    1.0
13    d        2    1.0
14    d        3    1.0
15    d        4    1.0
```

Comment: This is also a very nice answer and hard to decide but I went with the other one based on the timeline. Thank you!

Comment: Good answer, but it contains a slight bug: if a quarter is entirely missing from the original frame, it won't appear in the result either. For example, if the original frame has no data for Q4 of all types, the output will similarly have no Q4

Comment: @CodeDifferent yes I said it in the the text 'assuming each quarter is available in at least one type', maybe it was not said well :)